# Sql Query in delphi xe3 not working

Tags: sql, delphi

I am trying to execute a simple select*from statement with delphi but cannot get it to work. Please assist.

```
With Data.personel Do
 Begin
   Active:=False;
   Sql.Text:='Select*From personel where (name like ''%'+Combobox1.Text+'%'') and (surname like ''%'+Combobox2.Text+'%'') and (id_number like ''%'+Combobox3.Text+'%'') sort by '+sortfield1+','+sortfield2+','+sortfield3;
   Active:=True;
 End;
```

Sortfield1,2,3 are just variables that change when the sort comboboxes are changed.

I keep getting the same error, that there is a missing operator. I cannot figure out what is wrong. any assistance would be great, thanks.

Comment: nevermind, i just realized, it's suppose to be order by not sort by... Stupid me:D

Answer (score 2):

```
With Data.personel Do
  Begin
    Active:=False;
    Sql.Text:='Select * From personel where ' +
              '(name like '          + QuotedStr('%' + Combobox1.Text+'%')   + ') ' +
              'and (surname like '   + QuotedStr('%' + Combobox2.Text +'%')  + ') ' +
              'and (id_number like ' + QuotedStr('%' + Combobox3.Text + '%') + ') ' +
              'order by ' + sortfield1 + ',' +
                            sortfield2 + ',' +
                            sortfield3;
    Active:=True;
  End;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
With Data.personel Do
 Begin
   Active:=False;
   Sql.Text:='Select*From personel where (name like ''%'+Combobox1.Text+'%'') and (surname like ''%'+Combobox2.Text+'%'') and (id_number like ''%'+Combobox3.Text+'%'') Order by '+sortfield1+','+sortfield2+','+sortfield3;
   Active:=True;
 End;
```

"Order by", not "Sort By".

Stupid mistake but very hard to see if not looking for it